# What is the KAK (Cartan) decomposition in $\text{SL}(d, \mathbb R)$ in terms of linear algebra language (and its relation with SVD)?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G= \text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$ and consider its [Cartan decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_decomposition#Cartan_decomposition_on_the_Lie_group_level) in the Lie group level $G=KAK$. Here $K$ should be the compact group $\text{SO}(d,\mathbb R)$ and $A$ is a diagonal matrix (please correct me if I am wrong).

On the other hand, $\forall g \in G$ has a [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Singular_values,_singular_vectors,_and_their_relation_to_the_SVD). $g=U\Sigma V^T$ where $U,V$ are orthogonal and $\Sigma$ is diagonal whose diagonal entries are singular values (all positive). Here all matrices are real square matrices.

If my understanding is correct, then the KAK decomposition of $G$ is essentially SVD (up to the changing signs of the determinant for U,V and the entries of diagonal matrix in the middle). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: $A$ is not a diagonal matrix but the set of diagonal matrices I believe.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.